# How can I animate my background in SpriteKit adding for 3 times an image?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a background in my spritekit project declared as SKSpritenode that I want to animate every time the user loses a life (3 lives) adding an image, basically I have an image that I want to appear 3 times on top of each other, how can I do?

Comment: Hi userfab. Your question is a bit too broad. Are you having trouble adding a spritenode. animating the node, stacking nodes or running the code if a life is lost? You need to be more specific in your question and show any attempts you have already made to solve the issue. If you are just starting out and want to just figure out the basics, I suggest you look at this site https://www.raywenderlich.com/ios/

Comment: I don't know how to bring up an image when the user loses a life, but the game is already complete so I already have the lost life function, I only need to bring up an image in the view